# How to calculate number of business days between 2 dates with Moment.js inclusive of start and end dates

Tags: momentjs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days is super helpful but it doesn’t appear to be able to calculate *inclusive* difference between two dates.

In my example, I am trying to calculate PTO (paid time off) days.

So, if Friday, November 27th is a PTO day, then 2020-11-27 to 2020-11-27 should equal 1 day.

`moment("2020-11-27").businessDiff("2020-11-27"); // => 0`

I could add +1 but this will cause problems for other ranges.

1. For instance `moment("2020-11-27").businessDiff("2020-11-27") + 1; // => 1` is now correct
2. But `moment("2020-11-27").businessDiff("2020-11-29") + 1; // => 2`, which is incorrect.

What I need is this…

1. 2020-11-27 to 2020-11-27 equals 1 business day
2. 2020-11-27 to 2020-11-28 also equals 1 business day because the 28th is a Saturday

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
if(date1 === date2 && moment(date1).isBusinessDay()){
   businessDay = 1;
}else {
   businessDay = moment(date1).businessDiff(date2)
}
```